# I cannot see the audio sample I pulled from the circular buffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I'm new to iOS programming and currently working on a project that demodulates FSK signal. I adapted Michael Tyson circular buffer implementation but when I try to log out the samples to see whether it resembles the a square wave all i see I a constant value '67638612'. I already have a circuit that sends the FSK modulated signal through the mic of the audiojack.
here is the code I used to log out the samples:

```
// Init circular buffer
BOOL TPCircularBufferInit(TPCircularBuffer *buffer, int32_t length);

// Listing 10.28 Initial Setup of Render Callback from RemoteIO
static OSStatus InputFSKDemodulationRenderCallback (

                                                void                        *inRefCon,            // A pointer to a struct containing the complete audio data
                                                //    to play, as well as state    information such as the
                                                //    first sample to play on this invocation of the callback.
                                                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, // Unused here. When generating audio, use ioActionFlags to indicate silence
                                                //    between sounds; for silence, also memset the ioData buffers to 0.
                                                const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,   // Unused here.
                                                UInt32                      inBusNumber,    // The mixer unit input bus that is requesting some new
                                                //        frames of audio data to play.
                                                UInt32                      inNumberFrames, // The number of frames of audio to provide to the buffer(s)
                                                //        pointed to by the ioData parameter.
                                                AudioBufferList             *ioData         // On output, the audio data to play. The callback's primary
                                                //        responsibility is to fill the buffer(s) in the 
                                                //        AudioBufferList.
                                                ) {
AudioStruct* effectState = (AudioStruct*) inRefCon;
// Listing 10.29 Copying Captured Samples to Play-Out Buffer in RemoteIO Render Callback
// Just copy samples
UInt32 bus1 = 1;
CheckError(AudioUnitRender(effectState->rioUnit,
                           ioActionFlags,
                           inTimeStamp,
                           bus1,
                           inNumberFrames,
                           ioData),
           "Couldn't render from RemoteIO unit");

// Listing 10.30 Performing FSK demodulation Effect on a Buffer of Samples
// Walk the samples
AudioUnitSampleType* outSample = (AudioUnitSampleType* )ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
AudioUnitSampleType sample = (AudioUnitSampleType) &outSample;
memset(outSample, 0, inNumberFrames * kUnitSize * 2);

// if (effectState->bufferIsReady && !effectState->playbackWasInterrupted){

    for (int bufCount = 0; bufCount<ioData->mNumberBuffers; bufCount++){
        int currentFrame = 0;
 while (currentFrame <= inNumberFrames) {
    // Pull audio from circular buffer
int32_t availableBytes;
AudioUnitSampleType *bufferTail     = TPCircularBufferTail( &effectState->circularBuffer,     &availableBytes);

memcpy(outSample, bufferTail, MIN(availableBytes, inNumberFrames * kUnitSize * 2) );
TPCircularBufferConsume(&effectState->circularBuffer, MIN(availableBytes, inNumberFrames *   kUnitSize * 2) );
effectState->currentSampleNum += MIN(availableBytes / (kUnitSize * 2), inNumberFrames);

     NSLog(@" currentsamplenumber  is: %ld", sample);
```

on the console this is all i see:

```
2013-08-26 15:55:27.886 ElisaDongle[880:907] hardwareSampleRate = 44100.000000
RIO started!
2013-08-26 15:55:28.013 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.016 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.018 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.020 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.022 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.024 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.026 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.031 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.036 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.038 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
2013-08-26 15:55:28.041 ElisaDongle[880:6403]  currentsamplenumber  is: 67638612
```

Please, I need help. is there anything i'm doing wrong or missing. Feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Did you verify your incoming audio? Are you sure whatever mBuffers[0].mData holds makes sense to you?  I.e., data is not very small or clipping?   Sorry, didn't have time to go through your code but felt inclined to ask the "stupid questions" first.

Comment: @Yohst thanks for the reply. I was able to verify the incoming audio from the audio jack, it showed the waveform (a square wave) but I just cannot see any change in the samples now

Comment: "no change in samples" means mBuffers[].mData contains identical values?  If so, that means your sampling/input is not set up correctly. I remember going through this process, and finding it a bit tricky to work right. Perhaps post your set up code here so we can take a look at it?